# How can I get Ubuntu to load as a dual boot on an HP Envy laptop with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, 16.04, hp

I have a new HP Envy laptop (AMD A10 processor, Radeon R6, 8GB RAM, 2TB HD) with Windows 10. I don't want to use Windows as the main OS, and want to use Ubuntu (my previous laptop was Ubuntu, and in total, I have a number of Ubuntu systems).
I was able to set up the dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04. Sadly, when it loads, it hangs. I have tried live CDs of Ubuntu 12.04.5 and Fedora, but all have the same issue. I can't install Ubuntu first, as I suspect that it may not load, and then I could not install Windows as a dual boot, as I only have the backup/ system recovery.
What is awry that the live CDs won't work at all?
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If new UEFI based system, then it will be UEFI. And you will need newest Ubuntu to be compatible. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? And have you tried nomodeset on linux line in grub menu? But AMD drivers are changing. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes and:  System should use either the amdgpu driver or the radeon driver (depending on the available hardware).

Answer (score 0):

in the first place, have you try running the live cd in your new HP?
Try the application before installation could actually know if the system suits the ubuntu OS

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have Ubuntu installed on this machine?

How does it is partitioned?

Don't know about Windows, but you could install grub on MBR.

Copy this on a USB stick and boot it to see if you can restore your boot loader:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/